# Vim session with splits with remote ssh files

Tags: linux, vim, vimrc, macvim, vim-plugins

I use to use vim session to keep my opened files. I do it remotely, ssh remote machine and do things there.

Today I tried to open remote files in local Vim, I mean with netrw:

```
:e scp://user@remoteip//home/user/ ...
```

That works :)

And I can open files in split view also.

The advantage of this aproach is that I can work with my Vim, which is newer then the one on the server. Besides that, now I have just one .vimrc to take care.

Now to the problem. When I save the session it do not keep the splits, just one split is restored. Let's say I open two remote files each in one split, then I save session (:mks session.vim) and quit. When I restore session (vim -S session.vim) just one split.

My local .vimrc has:

```
set sessionoptions=sesdir,winsize
```

Why am I losing the splits?